# Meaning of "nothing too out of the ordinary"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm currently reading a [*Huffington Post* article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/nasa-rover-mars-light-flash-084121307.html) by Ed Mazza ("A Glint of Light and a Hint of Life: Mars Is Getting Very Interesting Right Now," June 24, 2019) and I came to a paragraph.

The paragraph says:

> It doesn’t appear on any of the images snapped before or after, taken about 13 seconds apart, so if it was an object of some kind it moved quickly. More likely, however, **it was nothing too out of the ordinary.**

I'm unable to grasp the meaning of the bold part. What could this line mean? Could that mean "it was nothing, which like other stuff out of the ordinary?" I don't get the meaning. Could someone please explain to me what this line means within the above context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nothing too out of the ordinary" means that the object was probably nothing not-ordinary/abnormal. The object was likely ordinary/normal.

Some synonyms for "out of the ordinary" would include *unusual, strange*, or *unheard of*. You can see [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/out%20of%20the%20ordinary) for a full list "out of the ordinary" synonyms:

Here is the [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20the%20ordinary):

> **out of the ordinary** (*idiom*) unusual, different, or strange : not what is considered to be normal
>   *What happened is nothing out of the ordinary*.

Comment: Thanks! In my almost 25 years English related life, I have heard for the first time "out of the ordinary" would be the potential synonym of "ordinary"! haha.

Comment: "Out of the ordinary" is actually an antonym of "ordinary." Sorry I didn't make that clear!

Comment: Thanks. But the synonym list you gave me helped a lot!

Comment: It's worth noting that "out of the ordinary" is an established idiom. (You wouldn't hear a native speaker saying "out of the normal" or "out of the usual".)

Comment: @J.R Thanks for the additional info. Let us forget about the difference of our opinions prior.